# Неправильное отображение формата файлa при работе с директориями

Tags: php, html

Всем доброго времени суток
При выводе на экран иерархию файлов в директории неправильно определяет тип файла,с чем может быть это связано?

```
<?php
function reader_directory($path, $level = 0)
{
    $space = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++) {
        $space .= "-";
    }
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $d = opendir($path);
        $mass = " ";
        do {
            if ($mass != "." && $mass != ".." && $mass != " ") {
                if (is_dir($mass)) {
                    echo $space . "[DIR]" . $mass . "<br>";
                    reader_directory($path . "/" . $mass, $level + 5);
                } elseif (is_file($mass)) {
                    echo $space . "[FILE]" . $mass . "<br>";
                } else {
                    echo $space . "[OTHER]" . $mass . "<br>";
                }
            }
        } while ($mass = readdir($d));
        closedir($d);
    }
}

reader_directory(".", 1);
?>
```

Сам вывод на экран[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В is_dir надо передавать полный путь, а не только конечное имя файла.
В папке upload `text3.txt` имеет тип `FILE` только потому, что это тип файла `text3.txt` из корневой директории.

Добавил изменения в ваш код для корректной его работы.

```
<?php
function reader_directory($path, $level = 0)
{
    $space = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++) {
        $space .= "-";
    }
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $d = opendir($path);
        $mass = " ";
        do {
            if ($mass != "." && $mass != ".." && $mass != " ") {
                if (is_dir($path . "/" . $mass)) {
                    echo $space . "[DIR]" . $mass . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                    reader_directory($path . "/" . $mass, $level + 5);
                } elseif (is_file($path . "/" . $mass)) {
                    echo $space . "[FILE]" . $mass . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                } else {
                    echo $space . "[OTHER]" . $mass . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        } while ($mass = readdir($d));
        closedir($d);
    }
}

reader_directory(".", 1);
?>
```

Comment: Можно чуть по-подробнее. В смысле полный путь?
Я же указал,что $path(данная директория)+/+$mass(еще 1 директория)

Comment: @tweeker Дополнил ответ

Comment: Обратите внимание на `is_dir($path . "/" . $mass)` и `is_file($path . "/" . $mass)`

Comment: Крч проще говоря,лучше всегда указывать "корневую"(главную) директорию?)

Comment: Не лучше всегда указывать корневую, а необходимо указывать путь к файлу. $mass - имя файла без пути. $path - путь к файлу без имени самого файла. Программа всегда должна знать, что делать, она не может угадывать.

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь `SPL Итераторами`:

```
function reader_directory($path)
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
      new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
      RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
      echo str_repeat('-', $iterator->getDepth()*5+1);

      if ($fileinfo->isDir()) echo '[DIR]';
      elseif ($fileinfo->isFile()) echo '[FILE]';
      else echo '[OTHER]';

      echo $fileinfo->getFilename()."\n";
    }
}

reader_directory(".");
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,но к сожалению,я пока изучаю php,до этого не дошел.Но все же благодарю,что расписали.Позже зайду и разберусь с этой темой)